# How to use `when` with 2 sealed classes and getting the inner value?

Tags: kotlin

Consider this extreme simplified code (available on https://pl.kotl.in/bb2Irv8dD):

```
sealed class Person {
    data class A(val i: Int) :
        Person()
}

fun main() {
    val a = Person.A(i = 0)
    val b = Person.A(i = 1)
    
    // Compiles
    when (a) { 
        is Person.A -> print("I have access to {$a.i}")
    }
    
    // Does not compile :(
    when (a to b) { 
        is Person.A to is Person.A -> print("I have access to {$a.i} and b {$b.i}")
    }
}
```

Why does the `(a to b)` code not work? It works for 1 variable, I was hoping I can match on both classes and get both inner values.

The error is:

> Incompatible types: Person.A and Pair<Person.A, Person.A> Expecting
> '->' Expecting an element Incompatible types: Person.A and
> Pair<Person.A, Person.A>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Aside from that syntax not being supported (you can only use `is` on one thing in a `when` branch), by using `to` you're literally creating an instance of the Pair class.

Pair uses generics for the types of its two variables, so this type information is lost at runtime due to *type erasure*.

So although, you *can* do this:

```
when (a to b) { 
    is Pair<Person.A, Person.A> -> print("I have access to {$a.i} and b {$b.i}")
}
```

it is only allowed when both `a` and `b` are local variables whose types are declared locally, so that the generic types of the Pair are known at compile time. But this makes it mostly useless, because if `a` and `b` are local variables with known type at compile time, then you could just replace the above with true or false.

To be able to do something like this in a general way, you must either create local variables to use:

```
val aIsTypeA = a is Person.A
val bIsTypeA = b is Person.A
when (aIsTypeA to bIsTypeA) {
    true to true -> //...
    //...
}
```

or use `when` without a subject and put the full condition on each branch:

```
when {
    a is Person.A && b is Person.A -> //...
    //...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The (a to b) returns a Pair<Person.A,Person.A> but what you are checking is Type Person.A to Type Person.A instead of the Type Pair<Person.A,Person.A>.

What you can do instead is:

```
when (a to b) { 
    is Pair<Person.A,Person.A> -> print("I have access to {$a.i} and b {$b.i}")
}
```